# How can i load data from a json file

Tags: json, extjs, load, var

i use extjs and load a json file with the store loader.

I want to load a json file. It will contain "totalRecords" and i want to put this in a var. For example var Records. This way i can display it at some positions of my app and use it for alerts.

thanks to your help i know have this:

```
total = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'step1',
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'testevents.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'slaevents'
        }
},
listeners: {
    load: function() {
        records = total.getRange()
        test = records[0].get('event')
        alert('1 =' +test)
    }
},
autoLoad:true
});
alert('2 =' +test)
```

This will show  alert with "1 =other". That is correct. And "2 =undifined". That is wrong. How can i use the test outside of this store?

Thanks

Comment: i always use a loader. So it will load in a grid. Also i tried to do a count but that always returned 0. I just don't know how to do it

Comment: i do use google but if you don't know what you are looking for it is hard. I edit with the code i try

Answer (score 2):

Realize that your store doesn't load instantly so it has nothing in it when you assign it to a variable immediately afterwards in the js. You need to listen for the store to load and then assign it, or assign it in a callback. For example, this works fine:

```
// get the countries
var countries = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id','name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: '../getCountries',
        reader: 'json'
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function() {
            records = countries.getRange()
            alert(records[0].get('name'))
        }
    }
});
```

This alerts "Argentina".

`records` becomes an array of [`Ext.data.Model`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) objects each of which have all the methods that `Ext.data.Model` has. This is covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) in the API.

Comment: but i read somewhere that i can't use the record[0] outside of this store?

Comment: It would be record **s** [0]. I am not sure what you read, give this a whirl in your code, it works fine for me. Note that I am **not** doing "**var** records = ..." which would make "records" a local variable, instead it is a global variable so it is accessible anywhere in your code. Of course you also have to keep in mind the part I said in the beginning about the store not loading instantly. So you wouldn't be able to call records[0].get('name') when your js initializes because it is empty until the ajax returns. But you can put it in other functions that get called after the ajax returns.